# Save and Next in Angular JS with Modal Window Instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-scope, content-management-system

Im quite new to Angular JS and building a CMS system using it. Currently we have 30 - 40 Objects. Which we load into a list. When one is clicked this loads a Modal Window using the Modal Instance in Angular JS.

On the modal we then want Save and Close, Save and Next and Save and Prev.

We've got Save and close sorted and everything is going fine. But to save time we want to be able to just load the next object in the modal window without having to close it and reopen.

I've added some code and any help would be greatly appreciated!

I've put some code in the pastebin below. Basically I want a function on my ModalInstance which will load the next object in my list of objects.

http://pastebin.com/N5M02Aua

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a `Service` which serves the Collection of Objects and has an internal pointer which references to the current used Object within the Collection.

I provided an example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/0goxnkxh/

Hope that helps.